# HMAC-SHA1 Example not returning desired hash?

Tags: c++, cryptography, hmac, hmacsha1

I am using this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382379%28VS.85%29.aspx

Directly copied and pasted, and using the following link as a reference for checking the digest: http://buchananweb.co.uk/security01.aspx

I am confused on what I am doing wrong.  This example is for HMAC-SHA1, correct?  If anyone could tell me what is going wrong, or could point me into the right direction, that would be of much help.

Comment: The msdn example uses rc4 to derive a key from the input key is the same true for HMACSHA1()?

Comment: According to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC, it seems that rc4 is not used?  Why would MSN use rc4 to derive the key?  How can I use MSN to accomplish HMAC-SHA1.  Unless anyone knows external free libraries that are free.

Answer (score 2):

To start with don't try to use complex key derivation functions, just use a simple explicit key like `{ 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 ... }`.  Alternatively find some HMAC-SHA1 test vectors, such as in [FIPS 198a](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips198/fips-198a.pdf), and use those keys as explicitly given.  The FIPS Test Vectors have the advantage of showing expected intermediate results as well so it is easier to pin down exactly where the problem is.

Using different key derivation functions will give you different HMAC results because the actual key used will be different if it is derived differently.